# How To Keep LI Numbers Inside OL

Tags: html, css

When the font size of the LI numbers increases the numbers leave the OL container (in pink).

Is there a way to increase the number size but keep everything inside of the pink area?

Here is an example:

```css
ol {
  background: pink;
}

li {
  font-size: 50px;
}

span {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <span>car</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>plane</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>boat</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: why not just add a `margin-left`

Comment: cause that seems hackish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ol {
  background: pink;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if youre going to just use a fixed font-size of 50px you could simply add a padding to the OL element:

```
ol {
  padding-left: 70px;
  background: pink;
}
```

however, if youre going to use something cooler, you could do something like this:

```
ol {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: my-awesome-counter;
}
ol li {
  counter-increment: my-awesome-counter;
}
ol li::before {
  content: counter(my-awesome-counter) ". ";
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: The custom counter is very cool, and adding the padding definitely works but I was wondering if there's a built in property specifically for getting the default OL numbers to play nice.

Maybe a display: property or similar that gets it to stay inside? But maybe messing with the spacing is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code

```css
 ol {
      background: pink;
      list-style-position: inside;
    }
```

```html
    <ol>
      <li>
        <span>car</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>plane</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span>boat</span>
      </li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: The guy already answered it why are you reposting his solution lol

Comment: Sorry i not seen loool :D